# Deploy an Amazon sagemaker-generated XGBoost model in R environment

Tags: python, r, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to deploy an `XGBoost` model , which is trained using Amazon sagemaker, in an `R` environment. The sagemaker-generated model is stored as a `Python` pickle object.

Using the `{reticulate}` package in R, I'm able to import the model into R. However, using the model locally in R gives very different predictions as compared to using the model directly on `Amazon sagemaker`, on the same testing dataset. I suspect there might be issues converting a `XGBoost` model stored by python into a model usable in R. Here is the relevant code I used to make the conversion:

```
library(reticulate)
library(xgboost)

model <- py_load_object("sagemaker-model")
# save the model locally, to be reload into R
model$save_model("local-model")
model_R = xgb.load("local-model")
```

The reason I first save the "sagemaker-model" locally and then use R to read it back is because I want to use native xgboost in R to make predictions, and not rely on reticulate for predictions. However, the predictions are clearly not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in Python, xgboost requires np.array as input. So  you have to convert the input with the Dmatrix function.

Something like this:

```
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(train$data, label=train$label)
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if there is a way to directly "translate" the Python-based model into a model recognizable, and usable, by R? I was hoping to be able to do everything (i.e., generating DMatrix, loading model, deploying model) all natively in R.